# Adding dll in web application which is developing on MVC Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed a custom Comment Control using class library file
now i want to use the dll of this file in web application which is developing on MVC Framework
so what are the ways of adding and using this dll in this project

Answer (score 1):

MVC projects are no different from other project types. To add a reference to another assembly (DLL) you right click on our project in the solution explorer, select add reference and then select your dll file.

Comment: Should the dll be included in the bin folder?